# How to Configuring Prewikka for Bionic at First time?

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management

I trying to installing the `Prewikka` package a Security Information and Events Management System based a Web Interface for Bionic.

I following the instructions on my terminal, when i getting started to setup `Prewikka` package, a confirmation appears :

[image]

i'm never provide configuring a password for the `Prewikka` Database, i try to find on a site [Docs](https://www.prelude-siem.org/projects/prelude/wiki) but i cannot find my issue exactly anything.

How do i know a password for my `Prewikka` on `dbconfig-common`? cause i choose the `dbconfig-common` Database as default on the instructions previously, see below!.

[image]

**Edit #1**

The Developer of Prewikka said *As for Prelude, we choose to use dbconfig-common, give the administrator password and enter the DB password.* on this [Docs](https://www.prelude-siem.org/projects/prelude/wiki/InstallingPackageUbuntu) for make the integration to Prelude Manager, therefore i choose `dbconfig-common` in the previous instructions. when i Reading all Docs of the Prelude Developer, i forgot to make a database for my Prewikka!. Oh that's my false. and this moment, i get some the Errors that i don't understand! but i still little bit confusing at the Confirmation a password which I have to enter a password between MySQL Database of Prewikka or DBConfig-Common of Prelude?

**Edit #2**

at this moment, i get some the Errors that i don't understand and really complicated to me! when i open the default port of Prewikka, the errors appears :

[image]

On my terminal appears :

```
$ sudo prewikka-httpd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 59, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 489, in __init__
    dh.apply()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 74, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 424, in apply
    self._apply()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 91, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 415, in _apply
    [ update.apply() for update in self.list() ]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 415, in <listcomp>
    [ update.apply() for update in self.list() ]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 87, in inner
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 221, in apply
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/sql/install.py", line 72, in run
    """)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 211, in query
    self.db.query(q)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 547, in query
    return preludedb.SQL.query(self, sql)
RuntimeError: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/main.py", line 277, in process
    response = self._process_static(webreq) or self._process_dynamic(webreq)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/main.py", line 244, in _process_dynamic
    self._prewikka_init_if_needed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/main.py", line 134, in _prewikka_init_if_needed
    raise self._prewikka_initialized
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/main.py", line 122, in _prewikka_init_if_needed
    env.db = database.Database(env.config.database)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 873, in __new__
    return MySQLDatabase(config)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 61, in inner
    raise DatabaseError(message=text_type(e))
prewikka.database.DatabaseError: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/bin/prewikka-httpd", line 62, in application
    return wsgi.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/web/wsgi.py", line 161, in application
    core.process(WSGIRequest(environ, start_response))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/main.py", line 280, in process
    response = err.respond()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/error.py", line 106, in respond
    return self._html_respond()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/error.py", line 90, in _html_respond
    from prewikka import baseview
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/baseview.py", line 27, in <module>
    from prewikka import error, history, hookmanager, resource, response, template, utils, view
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/history.py", line 102, in <module>
    crontab.schedule("search_history", N_("Search history deletion"), "0 * * * *", _regfunc=history._history_cron, enabled=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/crontab.py", line 240, in schedule
    self._init_system_job(ext_type, name, schedule, enabled, _regfunc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 91, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/crontab.py", line 152, in _init_system_job
    res = env.db.query("SELECT 1 FROM Prewikka_Crontab WHERE ext_type=%s AND userid IS NULL", ext_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 547, in query
    return preludedb.SQL.query(self, sql)
RuntimeError: Table 'prewikka.Prewikka_Crontab' doesn't exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 59, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 489, in __init__
    dh.apply()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 74, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 424, in apply
    self._apply()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 91, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 415, in _apply
    [ update.apply() for update in self.list() ]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 415, in <listcomp>
    [ update.apply() for update in self.list() ]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 87, in inner
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 221, in apply
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/sql/install.py", line 72, in run
    """)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 211, in query
    self.db.query(q)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 547, in query
    return preludedb.SQL.query(self, sql)
RuntimeError: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/main.py", line 277, in process
    response = self._process_static(webreq) or self._process_dynamic(webreq)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/main.py", line 244, in _process_dynamic
    self._prewikka_init_if_needed()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/main.py", line 134, in _prewikka_init_if_needed
    raise self._prewikka_initialized
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/main.py", line 122, in _prewikka_init_if_needed
    env.db = database.Database(env.config.database)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 873, in __new__
    return MySQLDatabase(config)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 61, in inner
    raise DatabaseError(message=text_type(e))
prewikka.database.DatabaseError: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/bin/prewikka-httpd", line 62, in application
    return wsgi.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/web/wsgi.py", line 161, in application
    core.process(WSGIRequest(environ, start_response))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/main.py", line 280, in process
    response = err.respond()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/error.py", line 106, in respond
    return self._html_respond()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/error.py", line 90, in _html_respond
    from prewikka import baseview
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/baseview.py", line 27, in <module>
    from prewikka import error, history, hookmanager, resource, response, template, utils, view
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/history.py", line 102, in <module>
    crontab.schedule("search_history", N_("Search history deletion"), "0 * * * *", _regfunc=history._history_cron, enabled=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/crontab.py", line 240, in schedule
    self._init_system_job(ext_type, name, schedule, enabled, _regfunc)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 91, in inner
    ret = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/crontab.py", line 152, in _init_system_job
    res = env.db.query("SELECT 1 FROM Prewikka_Crontab WHERE ext_type=%s AND userid IS NULL", ext_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/prewikka/database.py", line 547, in query
    return preludedb.SQL.query(self, sql)
RuntimeError: Table 'prewikka.Prewikka_Crontab' doesn't exist
```

**Edit #3**

I tried to following from this [issue](https://www.prelude-siem.org/boards/1/topics/153?r=157#message-157) and he solved with following :

- Deleted the Prewikka Database
- Recreated the Prewikka Database
- Retry to run the Prewikka

But it doesn't work to me, i also using the instructions like a mentioned it *Howto : https://www.prelude-siem.org/projects/prelude/wiki/InstallingPackageUbuntu*. so what i missing something guys??

Hope anyone can help me!, Thanks in advance.

Comment: as you said "i forgot to make a database for my Prewikka!" you want to continue without that? your question is with this clause? how to configure after forgetting to make a database?

Comment: @PRATAP no, when i tried to configuration of Prewikka, i forgot to make the MySQL Database for my Prewikka before i installing Prewikka package. so i still little bit confusing at the Confirmation `a password` which I have to enter a password between MySQL Database of Prewikka or DBConfig-Common of Prelude???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Installation Prelude and Prewikka Packages at first time :**

1. **Pre-Installation we need to have a database to store the alerts, i chose to make database in MySQL**

   ```sql
   $ mysql -u root -p
   Enter password: 
   Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
   Your MySQL connection id is 8
   Server version: 8.0.13 MySQL Community Server - GPL    
   Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.    
   Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective owners.    
   Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.    
   mysql>CREATE USER user1@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
   Query OK, 1 row affected (0,11 sec)    
   mysql>CREATE DATABASE prelude;
   Query OK, 1 row affected (2,09 sec)    
   mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON prelude.* TO user1@localhost;
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,93 sec)    
   mysql>CREATE DATABASE prewikka;
   Query OK, 1 row affected (2,10 sec)    
   mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON prelude.* TO user1@localhost;
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,94 sec)    
   mysql>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   mysql>EXIT;
   ```
2. **Prelude and Prewikka Installation required**

   ```bsh
   $ sudo apt install prelude-utils prelude-manager prelude-lml libpreludedb*
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   The following additional packages will be installed:
     dbconfig-common libmaxminddb0 prelude-lml-rules
   Suggested packages:
     dbconfig-mysql | dbconfig-pgsql | dbconfig-sqlite | dbconfig-sqlite3 | dbconfig-no-thanks mmdb-bin
   Recommended packages:
     default-mysql-client | postgresql-client
   The following NEW packages will be installed:
     dbconfig-common libmaxminddb0 libpreludedb0 libpreludedb7 libpreludedbcpp2 libpreludedb-dev libpreludedb-doc libpreludedb7-mysql libpreludedb7-pgsql libpreludedb7-sqlite prelude-lml prelude-lml-rules
     prelude-manager
   0 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   Need to get 968 kB of archives.
   After this operation, 3.881 kB of additional disk space will be used.
   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
   ```

   While `dpkg` is configuring, we will create a User Database, Name Database and Password Database stored on `dbconfig-common`. If we forgot them like in my case, we can check them in `/etc/prewikka/prewikka.conf` file.
3. **Configuration of Agents Registration.**

   The Manager Agent and The LML Client Agent are requires to run commands packages as analyzer log on Prelude admin.

   - First thing to add The Manager Agent with following :

     ```
     $ prelude-admin add prelude-manager --uid 0 --gid 0 #for user id and group id, you can check on `/etc/passwd` file.
     Generating 2048 bits RSA private key... This might take a very long time.
     [Increasing system activity will speed-up the process].
     Generation in progress... 
     Created profile 'prelude-manager' with analyzerID 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.
     ```
   - Second things to Register The LML Agent with following :

     ```
     $ prelude-admin register prelude-lml "idmef:w admin:r" 127.0.0.1 --uid 0 --gid 0
     Generating 2048 bits RSA private key... This might take a very long time.
     [Increasing system activity will speed-up the process].
     Generation in progress...   
     You now need to start "prelude-admin" registration-server on 127.0.0.1:
     example: "prelude-admin registration-server prelude-manager"  
     Enter the one-shot password provided on 127.0.0.1: 
     Confirm the one-shot password provided on 127.0.0.1:  
     Connecting to registration server (127.0.0.1:5553)... Authentication succeeded.
     Successful registration to 127.0.0.1:5553.
     ```

On The Manager Agent run:

```
$ prelude-admin registration-server prelude-manager
The "password" password will be requested by "prelude-admin register"
in order to connect. Please remove the quotes before using it.  
Generating 1024 bits Diffie-Hellman key for anonymous authentication...
Waiting for peers install request on 0.0.0.0:5553...
Waiting for peers install request on :::5553...      
Connection from 127.0.0.1:45796...
Registration request for analyzerID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" permission="idmef:w admin:r".
Approve registration? [y/n]: y
127.0.0.1:45796 successfully registered.
```

After validation of certificate, **don't** forget to configuration the listener of server on the `/etc/prelude/default/client.conf` file, `/etc/prelude/default/global.conf` file, `/etc/prelude-manager/prelude-manager.conf` file and `/etc/prelude-lml/prelude-lml.conf` file. and then we can start the service of Prelude :

```
$ sudo systemctl enable prelude-manager
$ sudo systemctl start prelude-manager
$ sudo systemctl enable prelude-lml
$ sudo systemctl start prelude-lml
```

**Finally** after executing `/usr/bin/prewikka` python script and we will get the listener server as `0.0.0.0:8000` and we can type to browse with `localhost:8000`, if the output errors is not appears then it will appears like below :

[image]

[image]

Sources : [Prelude-WikiStart](https://www.prelude-siem.org/projects/prelude/wiki/), [Installing-from-SourcesCode](https://www.prelude-siem.org/projects/prelude/wiki/InstallingPreludePrewikka), [Installing-from-PackageUbuntu](https://www.prelude-siem.org/projects/prelude/wiki/InstallingPackageUbuntu).